# I sent 1 ether to a scam ico anything i can do?

Tags: transactions

I sent 1 ethereum to quantslamp instead of quantstamp. Is there anyway I can report them? I'm assuming my money is already long gone

Comment: Nothing you can do as @xgabrielx said. Just be more carefull next time

Comment: You can try reporting to https://etherscamdb.info/

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately nothing that you can do once the ether has left your control and confirmed in a block.